# How can I return data from a Snowflake Native App running in a consumers' environment back to my provider account?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a Snowflake account that has its own schema & db and I'm creating a Snowflake Native App that works within the same ecosystem. I am able to share data from the provider account to the consumer account via views, however these only permit SELECT operations.

In reality, I need the Snowflake Native App to be able to modify the data in the provider's Snowflake such that the Snowflake Native App can perform INSERT & UPDATE statements the same way it can execute a SELECT through a mechanism like a view. What mechanisms are available to me to be able to create this functionality? Is this possible without using a convoluted API integration to reroute the data out of Snowflake and back in? Thanks!

I created a view in Snowsight in the Provider account on a Provider DB & SCHEMA:

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW NATIVE_APP.NATIVE_APP_SCHEMA.SOME_VIEW
AS SELECT *
FROM PROVIDER_DB.PROVIDER_SCHEMA.PROVIDER_TABLE;

Then I grant permissions to be able to access it:

GRANT SELECT ON VIEW NATIVE_APP.NATIVE_APP_SCHEMA.SOME_VIEW
TO SHARE IN APPLICATION PACKAGE NATIVE_APP_PACKAGE;

This works, however, views are read-only so what can I do to allow the native app to be able to write back to the provider db & schema?